# Component Not Updating When Data Changes - VueJS

Tags: cordova, vuejs2

so I've been struggling with this for a while. I'm working with [Quasar Framework](http://quasar-framework.org/) to build a test app. The problem I'm having is updating the component when data is received from the [contacts cordova plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts). This is the code I'm working with:

Showing the list:

```
<q-list>
      <q-item v-for="contact in myContacts">
        <q-item-main :label="getName(contact)" :sublabel="contact.phoneNumbers[0].value" />
        <q-item-side right icon="add circle outline" @click="addContact(getName(contact), contact.phoneNumbers[0].value, $event)" />
      </q-item>
</q-list>
```

My variable:

```
data () {
    return {
      myContacts: []
    }
}
```

Updating the `myContacts` variable.

```
mounted () {
    var self = this

    // Loader
    Loading.show({
      message: 'Loading...'
    })

    var cSort = function (a, b) {
      var an = a.name.formatted.toUpperCase()
      var bn = b.name.formatted.toUpperCase()
      return (an < bn) ? -1 : (an == bn) ? 0 : 1
    }

    var onConSuccess = function (contacts) {
      Loading.hide()
      self.myContacts = contacts.sort(cSort)

     alert(self.myContacts) // used to verify that the variable is getting updated
    }

    var onConError = function () {
      Loading.hide()
      Dialog.create({
        title: 'Oh no...',
        message: 'Error...',
        buttons: [
          'Ok'
        ]
      })
    }

    var options = new ContactFindOptions()
    options.filter = ''
    options.multiple = true
    var fields = ['*']
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onConSuccess, onConError, options)
}
```

Anyone know why my list isn't being updated when the `myContacts` variable is updated? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm it is being updated in any other way? (Logging, other places in the template...)

Comment: Yes, whenever I do an alert(self.myContacts) inside the success callback I get my JSON with my contacts.

Comment: Try `Vue.set(self, myContacts, contacts.sort(cSort))`

Comment: Didn't work. Also my alert doesn't work when I use `Vue.set()`.